# Clearing saved queries in phpMyAdmin MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to **PHP** and **MySQL**.

I created a database and I linked it to some login code I wrote in **PHP**. I must have clicked on the "SQL" section in the **phpmyadmin** interface because some half-written code is stuck there and I can't figure out how to remove it. It always runs when I refresh the table I created, and I just want it to go away.

I try to delete it from the SQL code section, but whenever I return to the page or refresh it appears back again, as if it is automatically loading it.

Please, someone help me remove the damn thing!

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

`(The SELECT * FROM users`) is the problem

Comment: what is this half written code ?

Comment: Are you using PHP/mysql? It sounds like you are in the phpmyadmin interface and are having issues there. Please provide code if using PHP/mysql.

Comment: @chris85 Hold on, I'll attach a photo.

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki Attached a photo

Comment: That is PHPmyadmin, there is not PHP here. This also is a bit off topic for SO because it is about software behavior and not an actual coding issue.

Comment: @chris85   So do you know how to remove it?

Comment: Not sure, maybe the `SQL` tab at the top. PHPmyadmin's behavior has varied for me, I'm mac based.

Comment: @chris85  Mac based too, can't seem to figure this one out...

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen this is the default phpmyadmin quey when you open the page! It's for showing all records of the table that you are selected. when you query from php file this default query and even phpmyadmin are not involved at all !  phpmyadmin is just a separate interface for developers to see the records!  you have a problem in your php code, show your code!

Answer (score 3):

This is phpmyadmin properties, It's a tool and having lots of feature.

1. In 1st screen you have clicked browse, so when u are trying to browse it will execute query to select all and will show the rows.
2. In 2nd screen you have clicked for the sql option. you can write your query here. by default `select * from table` is written, no need to worry in this , as you can remove this query and can write your own query here. there is a clear button also, can be useful to remove written query.

Hope this explaination is helpful.